# cell didn't return nil but it is not displayed

Tags: ios, uitableview, custom-cell

Apologies if this comes across as a beginner's question. I'm trying to populate a UITableView with sections and custom cell formatting.

i've debug this code and the label on each tag returns the correct value:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)cellForIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forData:(NSObject *)cellData {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MatterWIPCell";

RVMatterWIPExceptionSummary *matterWIPSummary = (RVMatterWIPExceptionSummary *)cellData;

UITableViewCell *cell = [self.searchableTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

UILabel *label;

label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
label.text = [[DataFormat dataFormat] stringLabelFormat: matterWIPSummary.fileNumber];

label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:2];
label.text = [[DataFormat dataFormat] stringLabelFormat: matterWIPSummary.clientName];

label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:3];
label.text = [[DataFormat dataFormat] stringLabelFormat: matterWIPSummary.matterTitle];

label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:4];
label.text = [[DataFormat dataFormat] currencyFormat:matterWIPSummary.workInProgress withDecimals:YES];

label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:5];
label.text = [[DataFormat dataFormat] stringLabelFormat:matterWIPSummary.matterDescription];

[cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
return cell;
```

}

i have checked the storyboard it uses the same cell identifier.

Did i miss something so the data won't display even the cell never returns nil?

Thank You

Comment: The text isn't being set. You have to say `cell.textLabel.text = label.text`. The label is just sitting there, not part of the cell.

Comment: but i set label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:];
it means on the storyboard to set the value into the right label on the table view cell isn't it?
it works on the other class but not in this class

Comment: You're making a copy of it right then with the same values, but they change one and you don't change the other. So you need to set it at the end.

Comment: i have tried using cell.textLabel.text = label.text but it still won't appear.

Comment: Try this: comment out all of the `label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
label.text = [[DataFormat dataFormat] stringLabelFormat: matterWIPSummary.fileNumber];` lines and do `cell.textLabel.text = @"Text";` or something like that and see what happens.

Comment: nothing happen.. it is still not displaying anything.

Comment: Do some logging. If after the line label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];, you log label, what does it return? After the next line, if you log label.text, what does it return?

Comment: It is return the correct value of the label, but the label won't display on the simulator.
as i investigate more it return nil for the visible cell but the cell return the correct value. i don't know how it can be happen

Comment: I'm sorry it's because my own mistake.

i have checked the code is correct.

Something missing in another method i called `[self.searchableTable SetHidden: YES]` it makes the visible cell returns nil.

Comment: You actually haven't mentioned what your problem is. Does the table view appear empty, or are some cells aren't being displayed?

Answer (score -1):

Add [cell.contentView addSubview:label]; before the return cell; And of course declare label with something like this UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, 320, 25)];